# Editing Excel worksheet while it is linked to an access table (and open)

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 excel workbooks, Main and Backup.

There is a macro run from Main every so often that transfers a row of data to Backup. Both these workbooks contain the exact same table.

I have an access database that is directly linked to the table in Backup, so I can view the data in my access database.

However, if my access database is open (or left open by an accident) then the macro from Main to Backup excel workbook does not work as it can only open it as "read only".

Is there a way to go around this? The main excel workbook is open 24/7 by the user that is why I came up with a second excel workbook as a "middle man" that is only opened briefly to insert data in. But of course this causes a problem if at the same moment there is data trying to be transferred. Main workbook is protected however Backup workbook is not.

I already tried "Allow changes by multiple users" on the Backup workbook. I am starting to think it is the way I "open" the workbook within my code in my main excel workbook?

My code is below, that basically opens up the Backup excel workbook and inserts a row of data into cells A3-BL3.

```
Sub TransferData()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Reportwb As Workbook


Set Reportwb = Workbooks("Main.xlsm")


Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\yilmadu001\Desktop\Backup.xlsx")


Reportwb.Sheets("Data1").Range("A4:BL4").Copy
wb.Sheets("DATA").Range("A3:BL3").Insert Shift:=xlDown
Reportwb.Save
wb.Close True


Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You should open your Excel spreadsheet within Access as Read-Only. If you can, try even modifying the file permissions to allow ReadOnly permission.

Comment: @SunnyPatel I have linked the excel datasheet to a table in access, is there a way to link it as "read only" ?

Comment: @SunnyPatel I never plan to edit the excel table  cells directly from access, I just want to be able to see the table, if that helps

Comment: I don't use Access, but I know enough that you should be able to link them as Read-Only. This way there is no conflict when writes are to be made to your .xls file.

Comment: Why have the Backup workbook at all? Why not just have the Main workbook insert into the Access table directly?

Comment: @JoshEller transferspread sheet method takes too long (table too big) I am not sure how to insert 1 line at a time into access, I know it is possible with ADO but no experience at all